# Solve Comparator does not return 0 for equal elements

Tags: java, return, comparator

Useful information:

### IDE: IntelliJ
JDK: 8u271

I have a warning which I do not understand nor do I know how to solve it.
Warning:

```
Comparator does not return 0 for equal elements
```

The warning highlights

```
(a, b)
```

within this line of code.

```
private final Comparator<Entity> renderSorter = (a, b) -> {
    if (a.getY() + a.getHeight() < b.getY() + b.getHeight())
        return -1;
    return 1;
};
```

What is the meaning of the warning and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add a case to check if two values are equal the comparator should return 0. Right now it will return `-1` or `1`.

```
private final Comparator<Entity> renderSorter = (a, b) -> {
    return Integer.compare(a.getY() + a.getHeight(), b.getY() + b.getHeight()); 
};
```

This will do the trick for you. Delegate the responsibility of comparision to the Integer class compare method.

Answer (score 1):

The contract of the `Comparator` interface says:

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

That warning is telling you that you Comparator never returns zero, which I assume you can see from examining your code.

You can solve the warning by making your Comparator return zero when the two Entity objects are equal, *in the sense of the Comparator*, not actually checking the two objects for equality.